# How to retrieve docs using Google Drive SDK in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, google-drive-api

I am working on a project that retrieve Google Drive docs list using ASP.NET, but I'm getting an error:

> An error occurred: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Daily Limit for
>   Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup. [403]

This is my site (getting error on this link) : http://www.netdesklive.com/

I am trying DrEdit code for this, but not working proper.

I set all the credential as per https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet but still i m getting an error

So Please, Suggest me

Code :

-> I am getting null value in state and code

```
public ActionResult Index(string state, string code)
{
    try
    {
        IAuthenticator authenticator = Utils.GetCredentials(code, state);
        // Store the authenticator and the authorized service in session
        Session["authenticator"] = authenticator;
        Session["service"] = Utils.BuildService(authenticator);
    }
    catch (CodeExchangeException)
    {
        if (Session["service"] == null || Session["authenticator"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect(Utils.GetAuthorizationUrl("", state));
        }
    }
    catch (NoRefreshTokenException e)
    {
        Response.Redirect(e.AuthorizationUrl);
    }

    DriveState driveState = new DriveState();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(state))
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        driveState = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<DriveState>(state);
    }

    if (driveState.action == "open")
    {
        return OpenWith(driveState);
    }
    else
    {
        return CreateNew(driveState);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi sshow, i put relavent code on this http://www.netdesklive.com/download/DrEdit.rar

Comment: please me help me to solve this

Comment: you should take out the relevant code and post it in the question. You can't ask anyone do download your `.rar` and find it themselves.

Comment: i put relavent code below, please help me to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Your error message suggests that your requests are not authorized. You should authorize them using Oauth2 :

- [Authorizing Drive requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials)
- [Google Oauth2 documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2)